# How to send multiple rows by selecting checkbox in datatable and send it to controller for update?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am working in ASP.NET MVC.
 I am having a datatable with checkbox options to select multiple rows to send to controller for bulk update. As, I am having two different funtions with two different buttons in same view, I cant able to use Form submission method.

I am trying to send via Ajax method. But, cant able to send selected rows into an array.

Codes that I tried below:
**Table:**

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%;" id="tblStatus" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-hd">
<thead>
    <tr class="gridheader">
        <td valign="middle" align="center" style="width: 2%;">
            <input id="chkAll" onclick="javascript: checkAll();" type="checkbox" name="chkAll" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%;" >Data1</td>
        <td style="width: 25%;" >Data2</td>
        <td style="width: 25%;" >Data3</td>
        <td style="width: 25%;" >Data4</td>   
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model != null)
        {      
         foreach (var m in Model)
         {
             <tr>
                 <td valign="middle" align="center" style="width: 2%;">
                     <input id="chkBox" name="chkBox" type="checkbox" onclick="javascript: checkManual();" value="" />
                 </td>
                 <td>Data1</td>
                 <td>Data2</td>
                 <td>Data3</td>
                 <td>Data4</td>                 
               </tr>
         }
        }    
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

**Controller:**

```
 [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Update(List<StatusVM> data1)
   {
       return View();
   }
```

**Button to Update:**

```
 <div class="btn-group">
      <button @*type="submit"*@ id="btnUpdate" onclick="GetData();" name="btnUpdate" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-flat"><span class="hide-on-mobile">Update </span><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>
```

**Javascript-Where I am trying to send data:**

```
 function GetData() {
        var table = $('#tblStatus').DataTable();
        if ($('[name="chkBox"]:checked').length <= 0) {
            alert('Please select minimum one data');
        }
        else {
             var CData = new Array();
            var dd;//= $('[name="chkBox"]:checked').toArray();
            $('[name="chkBox"]:checked').each(function (data) {
                 var rowData =table.row(this).data();
            CData.push(rowData);
            });
               $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Test/Update",
                contentType: "application/json;",
                headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': gettoken() },
                data: JSON.stringify({ data1: CData }),
            });
        }
    }
```

How to fix this? I want sent rows data that selected with checkbox only. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

From just looking at your javascript, I think your main issue is that you're not mapping the data you're sending to the `Controller` to the object that the `Update` Action Method is expecting and so the `Model Binding` is not working.

For example, say your `StatusVM` object looked like this:

```
public class StatusVM
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

In your javascript, you'll need to map the items from your html objects to that object, so create an object that represents it like in the example below:

```
var cData = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++){

    cData.push(obj);
}


function GetData() {
    var table = $('#tblStatus').DataTable();
    if ($('[name="chkBox"]:checked').length <= 0) {
        alert('Please select minimum one data');
    }
    else {
         var CData = new Array();
        $('[name="chkBox"]:checked').each(function (data) {
             var rowData =table.row(this).data();

        var obj = {
           Id: rowData.Id,
           Name: rowdata.Name
        };
        CData.push(obj );
        });
           $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Test/Update",
            contentType: "application/json;",
            headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': gettoken() },
            data: CData,
        });
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating table("DOM") in your view, row().data() will return "Array" of values of row. In your case it would be like row 1 data will be ["Data1", "Data2", "Data3"...].
In this case you have to make "StatusVM" like object in each function callback

```
$('[name="chkBox"]:checked').each(function(data) {
  var rowData = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
  var obj = {
    "col1": rowData[0],
    "col2": rowData[1],
    "col3": rowData[2]
  }
  CData.push(obj);
});
```

If you want the row return object then you have to bind DataTable with JSON.

As documentation says:

Data source object for the data source of the row. This will be an **array if you use DOM sourced data**, otherwise it will be the array / object / instance that is used to populate the table with data.